# Rename tag [mdm] into [mobile-device-management]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-disambiguation

Today, I was looking for questions about **Master Data Management** (usually called MDM) so I searched for [mdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdm) questions.

But [mdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdm) tag is currently used for **Mobile Device Management**

And **Master Data Management** tag is [master-data-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-data-management)

I think [master-data-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-data-management) tag is pretty clear but [mdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdm) is a little bit confusing.

I think it would great if [mdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdm) could be renamed into `mobile-device-management`

Comment: Why do I have the feeling I saw this question before?

Comment: When I search for Master Data Management, Mobile Device Management or MDM in Meta, I have nothing. If you have a link, I can delete my question and upvote the other instead.

Comment: Yeah, I tried google and SEDE and couldn't find it either.

Comment: @rene, may have been during your may-delete-memory work.  Did you forget about that?

Answer (score 4):

Admittedly, 'mdm' does seem a bit generic considering the scope of these examples. It's likely that some other acronyms may be required to have their elaborated meanings tag-specific as well. Professionally, I've only run into the Master Data Management meaning myself.

Comment: However, from my side I've mostly only ran into Mobile Device Management myself. MDM is ambiguous about what it means and should be removed.

Comment: Fun fact... for me, Googles first page of search results for MDM is 100% Mobile Device Management.... except for the ads, those are 100% Master Data Management.